# Rename duplicate result from query with left join and group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, mysql-5.5

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
category,
description
FROM `players` 
INNER JOIN orders ON orders.id_player = players.player
GROUP BY id_p
```

This is result:

```
category           description
1                  tv
1                  radio
1                  computer
2                  hamburger
```

I'd like get something like this:

```
category        description
1                 tv
-                 radio
-                 computer
2                 hamburger
```

How should I change my query?
Thanks

*made database changes

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

Using `ROW_NUMBER()` with `CASE` you can achieve the expected  result:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
        (PARTITION BY order_player ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) = 1 
       THEN order_player ELSE '-' END
       ) AS order_player,
    description
FROM `players` 
INNER JOIN orders ON orders.id_player = players.player
GROUP BY id_p
```

Comment: how do you know that OP's mysql version support row_number()

Comment: *"how do you know that OP's mysql version support row_number()"* wait... @fa06 everybody nowadays is running MySQL 8 because it's much better in every way??

Comment: @RaymondNijland -ha ha ha :D

Comment: Thank you for help. 
I get this error > #1064 -  syntax error near  'OVER 
        (PARTITION BY order_player ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) = 1 
       T' linea 1

Comment: mySql version is 5.5. Made database changes.

Comment: MySQL 8.0 is one giant delay for SQL-kind https://modern-sql.com/blog/2018-04/mysql-8.0

Answer (score 0):

5.5

Use this pattern:

Live test: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dicEcARLUJpYLcWTULsb4n/0

```
select category, description
from 
(
  select
      case when t.category <> @category then 
          t.category
      else
          '-'
      end as category,
      description,
      @category := category
  from tbl t cross join (select @category := '') x
  order by t.category, description
) y
```

Output:

```
|    category | description |
|-------------|-------------|
| electronics |    computer |
|           - |       radio |
|           - |          tv |
|        food |   hamburger |
```

Comment: Hi, I'm working on your query.
I posted only an example of my working query, but I would need of inner join with 'players' table.